# 2 DataTemplates within each other, Command not found

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate, icommand

My `ICommand` is not firing when i touch my button...

I have a DataTemplate within a DataTemplate... does DataContext still refer to the entire page or is it that DataContext refers to the previous DataTemplate and that's why it cannot find my view model's `ICommand`?

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource xLightGray}" Margin="0,0,0,10" Padding="0,0,0,10">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="0" Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Image Source="{Binding image.thumbnail_link}" Width="40" Height="40"></Image>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="OrganisationItemList"
                Background="Transparent"
                ItemsSource="{Binding spaces}" 
                LayoutMode="List"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Background="Red" Style="{StaticResource xTransparentButton}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoadSpaceCommand, ElementName=SpaceList}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Padding="0,0,0,5" Margin="0" Height="auto" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="True" FontSize="0.01">
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                                <TextBlock Padding="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="{StaticResource xFontSize}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, you must set `ElementName` in the binding to the parent ListBox:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoadSpaceCommand, ElementName=OrganisationList}"
```